# How to properly install srcML?

Tags: 12.04, software-installation

I'm trying to install a program called srcML. I got it from http://www.srcml.org/downloads.html

I got the `.tar.gz` file and extracted it and I'm left with a `./bin`, `./include`, `./lib` folder.

When trying to run the binary file I get the error

> ./srcml: error while loading shared libraries: libsrcml.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to properly install it?

Comment: First, you might want to [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/781144/edit) your question and add where you got that `.tar.gz` from.

Comment: @Videonauth  sorry about that.  I added the link.  It's a program called srcML that parses c++/java code.  It doesn't seem to be very popular so finding solutions is a little difficult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it probably more easily using the `.deb` files provided on that download site. Open a terminal () and depending on your architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) choose the right commands, I put comments on them:

```
# 64-bit
wget http://131.123.42.38/lmcrs/beta/srcML-Ubuntu12.04-64.deb
sudo dpkg -i srcML-Ubuntu12.04-64.deb

# 32-bit
wget http://131.123.42.38/lmcrs/beta/srcML-Ubuntu12.04.deb
sudo dpkg -i srcML-Ubuntu12.04.deb
```

Comment: You're very welcome.